# Angular Material Datepicker crashes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) as a date range input. when I click on the toggle icon to show the date picker I get 2 violations:

> [Violation]Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

> [Violation]Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Then as soon I select a date the dialog disapears (auto cancels).